# Null Pointer Exception while setting value of TextView in an Array Adapter class - Android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` while trying to start an Activity which contains a `ListView` .

In the `getView` method of the adapter class, the exception happens when the `setText` function of a `textView` is being called .

The code bellow is my adapter class:

```
public class QuestionsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Question> {

    Context context;
    List<Question> questions;

    public QuestionsListAdapter(Context context, List<Question> questions){

        super(context, R.layout.list_item_question, questions);
        this.context = context;
        this.questions = questions;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_question, null);

        Question question = questions.get(position);

        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.question_list_item_string);

        Log.i(TableCreator.LOG_TAG, question.toString()); //this works fine and the string is not null .

        tv.setText(question.toString()+""); //NULL POINTER EXCEPTION .

        return view;
    }
}
```

As you see, I've logged the string in the logcat and it works just fine, but the next line makes the mistake .
And this is the logcat output:

```
05-27 13:24:02.979    5325-5325/org.kabiri.operationcheklist I/Operation Checklist﹕ |-Question-> id:1 summary:mySummary comment:myComment solution:mySolution ownerList:dummyOwner
05-27 13:24:02.979    5325-5325/org.kabiri.operationcheklist D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-27 13:24:02.979    5325-5325/org.kabiri.operationcheklist W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0f5f648)
05-27 13:24:02.979    5325-5325/org.kabiri.operationcheklist E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.kabiri.operationchecklist.adapter.QuestionsListAdapter.getView(QuestionsListAdapter.java:43)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:736)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1655)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:502)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The logcat shows that the error happens on this line of my adapter class:

```
tv.setText(question.toString()+"");
```

I really appreciate your help .

Comment: does your xml contain TextView with id "question_list_item_string"?

Comment: Yes, it has the TextView with id "question_list_item_string" .

Comment: Is your list of questions non-null? Are all items non-null? Debug your app

Comment: Yes, it has one record in this situation, considering the first line of the logcat which shows the content of the item which is going to be showed and it is not null .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know where the problem is!

```
tv.setText(question.toString()+"");
```

is causing the NPE that means the `TextView tv` is `null`. And that means that the line

```
 TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.question_list_item_string);
```

is not able to find the TextView. Check the `question_list_item_string` id and make sure it matches the id in your `list_item_question.xml` file

Comment: YEAH, that's right, the id of the TextView "question_list_item_string" was available in my XML layout files, so the Android Studio was not showing any errors, but the TextView it was not located in its right XML file "list_item_question.xml" file and that was causing the runtime error . it seems that it was caused by a refactor which Android studio didn't handled; Thank You So Much .